# Inserting a ComboBox selection into a Text box - the ComboBox and Text box are inside separate methods

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, combobox, textbox

Below is a miniature of my code. I'm having trouble inserting the Combobox's selected option (real_optn) into the Text box. I couldn't even print out the option anywhere outside the binding method itself (display_option). The error I kept getting was "'Sample' object has no attribute 'real_optn'". In one of my trials, I used self.display_option(name) in the binding rather than self.display_option. This got it inserting but as one would expect, the selection wasn't updating. I have read through [Getting the selected value from combobox in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31264522/getting-the-selected-value-from-combobox-in-tkinter?rq=1), [Simple ttk ComboBox demo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757451/simple-ttk-combobox-demo/17757533#17757533) and a bunch of other related queries but non answered my query. Your hints are appreciated!

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import ttk

class Sample:    

    def __init__(self, master,title):
        frame.title(title)
        frame.geometry('1100x500')

    def combo_menu(self,page,name,options):
        self.variable = StringVar()
        self.name = ttk.Combobox(page,values=options)
        self.name.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.display_option) 
        current = self.name.current(0)
        self.name.pack()

    def display_option(self,event): 
        optn=self.name.get()
        mapping_dic = {
        "1": "A",
        "2": "B",
        "3": "C"
        }
        self.real_optn = mapping_dic.get(optn,"A")
        print(self.real_optn) 

    def output(self,page):
        OutputBox=Text(page)
        OutputBox.pack()
        OutputBox.delete("1.0", "end")
        OutputBox.insert(END, self.real_optn)

frame = Tk()
pop = Sample(frame, "Sample")
pop.combo_menu(frame,"first",[1,2,3,4])
pop.output(frame)

frame.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `pop.putput(frame)` before the window is visible, which means before the user can select anything, which means before you create `self.real_optn`.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. What do you suggest I do to get it working then? The issue is `real_optn` is not being recognised as an attribute of `pop` which is pretty strange considering that `display_option`   is a method in the class. In the reverse, I figured out that it worked perfectly if I move `OutputBox.delete("1.0", "end")` and `OutputBox.insert(END, self.real_optn)` inside `display_option`. But this doesn't work for my project as the users might want to change choices. Plus there are several other comboboxes I want to output to the same Textbox after choices are finalised.