# Get the index of a selected item in a ttk.Combobox

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

I am having trouble with IF statements when using combo boxes when using Tkinter. When I want the program to select speed distance time, the program instead selects speed acceleration time and all the other formulas in the dropdown list. Please can you help me with this?

```
dropdown = Combobox(root)
dropdown['values']=("Speed, Distance, Time", "Speed, Acceleration, Time", "Gravitational Potential Energy(Ep)", "Kinetic Energy (Ek)", "Elastic Potential Energy (Ee)", "Energy/Work Done, Power, Time", "Energy/Work Done, Force, Distance", "Energy, Voltage, Charge", "Specific Heat Capacity", "Specific Latent Heat", "Efficency", "Pover, Voltage, Current", "Power, Current, Resistance", "Current, Charge, Time", "Voltage, Current, Resistance")
dropdown.pack()

def clicked():    
    if dropdown['values'][0] == dropdown_formulae[0][0]: # if the user has selected the first option
        simpleFormulaMenu(0)
    elif dropdown['values'][1] == dropdown_formulae[1][0]:
        simpleFormulaMenu(1)
    elif dropdown['values'][2] == dropdown_formulae[2][0]:
        pass
    elif dropdown['values'][3] == dropdown_formulae[3][0]:
        pass
    elif dropdown['values'][4] == dropdown_formulae[4][0]:
        pass
    elif dropdown['values'][5] == dropdown_formulae[5][0]:
        simpleFormulaMenu(5)
    elif dropdown['values'][6] == dropdown_formulae[6][0]:
        simpleFormulaMenu(6)
    elif dropdown['values'][7] == dropdown_formulae[7][0]:
        simpleFormulaMenu(7)
    elif dropdown['values'][8] == dropdown_formulae[8][0]:
        pass
    elif dropdown['values'][9] == dropdown_formulae[9][0]:
        pass
    elif dropdown['values'][10] == dropdown_formulae[1][0]:
        pass
    elif dropdown['values'][11]:
        simpleFormulaMenu(11)
    elif dropdown['values'][12]:
        simpleFormulaMenu(12)
    elif dropdown['values'][13]:
        simpleFormulaMenu(13)



button = tk.Button(text = "Submit", command = clicked)
button.pack()
```

Comment: You should get the selected item in `dropdown`: e.g. `selected = dropdown.get()`, then use `selected` in those if statements instead of `dropdown['values'][...]`.

Comment: How should I use selected in the IF statements

Answer (score 1):

> **Question**: Get the index of a selected item in a `ttk.Combobox`

---

**Core point**: Use `<seq>.index` to get the index of the selected item

---

**Reference**

- [`s.index(x[, start[, end]])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#index-19)

  > Return zero-based index in the seq of the first item whose value is equal to x
- [`Combobox.get()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm)

  > The `.get()` method returns the current selected item of the `Combobox`
- [simple-ttk-combobox-demo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17757533/7414759)

  > Bind the virtual event `<<ComboboxSelected>>` to the Combobox widget

---

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.combobox = combobox = ttk.Combobox(self)
        combobox['values'] = ("Speed, Distance, Time",
                              "Speed, Acceleration, Time",
                              "Gravitational Potential Energy(Ep)"
                              )
        combobox.pack()
        
        button = tk.Button(text="Submit", command=self.on_clicked)
        button.pack()
    
    def on_clicked(self, *event):
        selected = self.combobox.get()
        if selected:
            idx = self.combobox['values'].index(selected)
            print('simpleFormulaMenu({}), selected: {}'.format(idx, selected))
            
            if idx in (2, 3, 4):  # pass
                pass
            else:
                # simpleFormulaMenu(idx)
                pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    App().mainloop()
```

***Tested with Python: 3.5 - 'TclVersion': 8.6 'TkVersion': 8.6***